# Which file types are associated with an Excel workbook that has a file format with a value of 63?

Tags: vba, excel, vsto

Does anyone know which file types are associated with an Excel workbook that has a file format with a value of 63? I have already looked at the MSDN article about the ["XlFileFormat Enumeration"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff198017.aspx), but I have not found the value of 63 there. Can anyone help or share a useful web link?

---

Update to deliver a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

1. Create a new blank .txt file and encode it as UTF-8 **with BOM** (you can use a program like [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) for that task)!
2. Open Microsoft Excel (I used Microsoft Excel 2010 32-bit for Windows)!
3. Within the opened Excel application open the newly created .txt file with "File" --> "Open"!
4. Within Excel create the following VBA macro and execute it to get the "XLFileFormat" value for the currently active workbook or rather the opened .txt file!

`Public Sub ShowFileFormatOfActiveWorkbook()
    MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.FileFormat
End Sub`

5. If you have followed the above instructions correctly, you should get a value of 63 (from Excel 2010, but a value of 64 from Excel 2013/2016).
6. Repeat the above instructions with an UTF-8 encoded .csv file! You will get a value of 63 (or 64 depending on the Excel version you use) again.

Do just UTF-8 encoded text-based files (e.g. .txt, .csv, .html) have a "XlFileFormat" value of 63 or do exist some more file types which match the mentioned "XlFileFormat" of 63?

Comment: I just tried a [Workbook.SaveAs method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx) with FileFormat:=63 to see what extension it added and received an error. Just for fun I tried 63 with [Worksheet.SaveAs method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195820.aspx); same problem. So the answer is: there is no valid [XlFileFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx) with a value of **63**. If you still think there is, please post a [mcve].

Comment: fwiw, it isn't in any of the [WdSaveFormat Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb238158.aspx) either.

Comment: It may not be in the [WdSaveFormat Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb238158.aspx), because Excel is still not able to save .csv files UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Yes it can if you choose SaveAs, Tools, Web options, Encoding, Unicode (UTF-8).

Comment: I ran through the mcve instructions, adding File origin: 65001: Unicode (UTF-8) in the text import wizard. The  `debug.print ActiveWorkbook.FileFormat` returned -4158 so if you are getting 63 then I suspect you are not using the correct codepage to import the TXT file.

Comment: Thanks for your further help! If you look at step 3 of my example, you will see that I did not use the text import wizard, but opened the .txt file directly with "File" --> "Open" instead..

Comment: When I use File, Open to open a TXT file I **always** get the Text Import Wizard. If you do not, then perhaps there is something askew with your file associations. If I use File, Open on a CSV I do not get the TIW but .FileFormat reports **6** not 63. This is due to the default **File Origin** codepage mentioned earlier.

Comment: May I ask which Excel version do you use (so I might be able to reproduce)?

Comment: I tested your method on xl2010 (ver 14.0.7166.5000 32-bit), xl2013 (ver 15.0.4805.1001 32-bit) and xl2016 (ver 16.0.6701.1011 32-bit). I received identical results.

Comment: Fortunately, I was able to reproduce your results with UTF-8 encoded files **without BOM**. I got my results with UTF-8 encoded files **with BOM**. Surprisingly, for Excel 2013 and Excel 2016 I got a "XlFileFormat" value of 64 instead of 63 (Excel 2010).